# why are my images loaded so slow to the listView?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, compression

I have a listView with ImageViews.

I try to compress the bitmaps with the following code:

```
    public void getImage(final String urlStr, final ImageView toSet) {
        // set the tag immediately, to prevent delayed image downloads from
        // setting this image.
        toSet.setTag(urlStr);

        getImage(urlStr, new ImageRepository.ImageRepositoryListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageRetrieved(final Drawable drawable) {
                if (drawable == null)
                    return;
                toSet.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // make sure the tag is still the one we set at the
                        // beginning of this function
                        if (toSet.getTag() == urlStr) {
                            toSet.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                            drawable.setCallback(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }


public class DownloadImageAsyncTask2 extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private final ImageView imageView;
        private String imageUrl;

        public DownloadImageAsyncTask2(ImageView imageView) {
            this.imageView = imageView;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i("DownloadImageAsyncTask", "Starting image download task...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            imageUrl = params[0];
            try {

                imageRepository.getImage(imageUrl, imageView);

                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                        imageUrl).getContent());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("DownloadImageAsyncTask", "Error reading bitmap" + e);
                downloadingImageUrls.remove(imageUrl);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

            imageCache.put(imageUrl, bitmap);
            downloadingImageUrls.remove(imageUrl);

            if (bitmap != null
                    && ((String) imageView.getTag()).equals(imageUrl)) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I make the image loading time be faster?

(I have tried to downsize the images on the server side, but I want to think what can I improve in the client side).

I use async download task to download the images and a cache layer to persist them.

Here is the code:

Comment: Have you considered using any of the open source libraries that handle all of this for you, like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)?

Answer (score 0):

Your image loading is slow because:

After downloading and saving images in the cache , the AsyncTask is used to load but it doesn't give the result immediately.

- Firstly, it is controlled by the global Thread's pool with the number maximum of thread in concurrence. Sometimes , it begins after finishing the other AsyncTask .
- Secondly, the method "onPostExecute" is executed in Main Thread but after finishing all the other messages of Main Thread.

So:

- Use AsyncTask only to download and save images in the cache.
- Try to check if the expected image exists in the cache before using AsyncTask. If it exists then you display it directly in Main thread. Make sure that the size of expected image fits well in your image view .

In your case , add the code like this:

```
public void getImage(final String urlStr, final ImageView toSet) {
    //get the expected image associated with this url and the size of this image view in the cache
    Bitmap bitmap = getExpectedBitmap(urlStr,expectedSize); 
    if(bitmap != null) {
        //if it exists , set it in the image view and finish.
        toSet.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        return;
    }

    // set the tag immediately, to prevent delayed image downloads from
    // setting this image.
    toSet.setTag(urlStr);

    getImage(urlStr, new ImageRepository.ImageRepositoryListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageRetrieved(final Drawable drawable) {
            if (drawable == null)
                return;
            toSet.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // make sure the tag is still the one we set at the
                    // beginning of this function
                    if (toSet.getTag() == urlStr) {
                        toSet.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                        drawable.setCallback(null);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```